# JWPlayer - add query parameter to ray-level manifest requests [Uplynk]

Tags: javascript, manifest, jwplayer, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I need JWPlayer to add a query parameter of `spc=Timestamp` when it is requests a ray-level manifest file.

I found something similar to this when reading the DRM documentation for JWPlayer however Uplink have advised that this is not DRM so the documentation solution will not work: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2561182-drm-digital-rights-management-

If anyone has any ideas please help.

Thanks.